# Desktop environment delivery via remote virtual server

Tags: server, remote

I've known since shortly after starting with various flavors of *nix circa '04 that the OS is a multi-user server environment. There remains a nagging issue that I just can't seem wrap my head around, and I'd like to solve it. Given that on effectively any virtual infrastructure (whether I own it or not) I can spin up this multi-user environment with relative ease and connect to it securely (as I can), and given that I can install and securely deliver applications at no additional cost per application via ssh command line, why is complete, open delivery of a desktop environment such a pain?

VDI solutions exist, but are nearly all geared towards Windows; this makes sense given that the Windows environment wasn't designed with multiple users in mind. Such tools that support Linux exist, but are far less prevalent.

Furthermore, solutions seem to exist within the current scope of *nix OSs and Ubuntu specifically via LTSP, but when put into a public space (remote server), LTSP (to my knowledge) breaks down.

Getting to the question (this isn't a rant; I'm just frustrated because I haven't yet found a solution to this issue), is there a way to deliver a full desktop experience (sound, video, something skype-ish) via remote Ubuntu Server to a local Ubuntu client (I'll worry about other platforms later) that doesn't involve software costs?

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04 (desktop and server) using LXDE delivered via xrdp -> everything works wonderfully, except for sound.
- Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04 (desktop and server) gnome-session-fallback via freenx -> mixed results: 12.04 worked fairly well and I'm still working on that [video only, so far], 14.04 was a total bust: the only that works is an ssh prompt.
- Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04 (desktop) applications deliverd ssh + x -> works, except for sound
- Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04 (desktop) desktop delivered via xephyr -> remote screens blank

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, [working with a few people on the Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2223938&page=2), I was able to get a solution working, but it uses `x2go` instead of `xrdp`.

First install openssh-server:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

You need to modify the sshd_config file, so make a backup

```
sudo cp /etc/shh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.back
```

open the file

```
sudoedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

find these lines

```
# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

and change that last `no` to `yes`

```
# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
```

Find these lines

```
# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes
```

And uncomment like so:

```
# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Now restart the service

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

Now install `x2go` from ppa on the server

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y lxde alsa pulseaudio paprefs x2goserver x2goserver-xsession
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
sudo apt-get clean
```

Add yourself to the `x2gouser` group

```
sudo adduser $USER x2gouser
```

On the client install the client package and `paprefs`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install paprefs x2goclient
```

In order to login to your remote server, start the `x2go` program and put in the IP address (or URL if you have one) and your username. Make any other configuration changes that need to be done, and then go back to the tab with your username. Instead of selecting LXDE as the session type, select custom desktop. In the field next to this selector, enter:

```
ck-launch-session startlxde
```